# Making android widget with more than one button

Tags: android, android-widget, click

I developed an android app and want to make a widget of it like google search widget, which has two click-able areas. From that widget i need to send parameters to app in order to decide which area has clicked and which feature of app should be open.
I appreciate any idea or any clue.

Best Regards
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a custom component. There are several ways of going about this depending on what you are after. A good overview of ways you can go about creating a custom component is given in this [Android Developer API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

From your explanation, a simple Compound Control (as described towards the end of the above guide), should do the job. Taking this approach, the Google search widget can be thought of as just a horizontal LinearLayout containing an EditText and a Button.